# How to get row of every 30 seconds time duration from array using Php

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, duration

Here I have One `Track Point` Array contain `bulk` of information like following Array data

Now i want to average of `['real_met']` index value of every 30 seconds. every 30 second is depend on `['acumulate_time']` index value. problem is some time time duration might be 1 or 2 second difference.

```
    Array
    (
        [trkpt] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:00
                [real_met] => 1.6266666666666
                [power] => 1078.3093333333
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:01
                [real_met] => 1355.1506666667
                [power] => 1118.4989777778
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:03
                [real_met] => 805.652
                [power] => 1109.5731111111
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:05
                [real_met] => 1111.084
                [power] => 1124.1473777778
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:06
                [real_met] => 1206.6186666667
                [power] => 1121.7764444444
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:07
                [real_met] => 1438.1333333333
                [power] => 1116.4999555556
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:08
                [real_met] => 1467.4213333333
                [power] => 1105.0636888889
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:09
                [real_met] => 1507.8666666667
                [power] => 1092.2327555556
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:10
                [real_met] => 1763.788
                [power] => 1078.7742222222
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:11
                [real_met] => 2023.8933333333
                [power] => 1058.5515555556
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:12
                [real_met] => 1576.2053333333
                [power] => 1033.3778222222
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:13
                [real_met] => 1191.2773333333
                [power] => 1017.2694222222
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:14
                [real_met] => 1128.5173333333
                [power] => 1016.6418222222
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:15
                [real_met] => 1548.312
                [power] => 1028.5894666667
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:16
                [real_met] => 1516.932
                [power] => 1025.5212
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:17
                [real_met] => 1540.6413333333
                [power] => 1020.3144444444
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:18
                [real_met] => 1538.5493333333
                [power] => 1014.6428
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:19
                [real_met] => 1739.3813333333
                [power] => 1009.8312
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:20
                [real_met] => 1012.76
                [power] => 998.46466666667
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:21
                [real_met] => 469.53733333333
                [power] => 982.44924444444
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:22
                [real_met] => 842.61066666667
                [power] => 987.84195555556
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:23
                [real_met] => 650.14666666667
                [power] => 974.73208888889
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:24
                [real_met] => 622.25333333333
                [power] => 972.03573333333
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:25
                [real_met] => 367.02933333333
                [power] => 960.99462222222
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:26
                [real_met] => 397.712
                [power] => 962.7612
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:27
                [real_met] => 567.86133333333
                [power] => 962.38928888889
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:28
                [real_met] => 597.84666666667
                [power] => 958.97235555556
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:29
                [real_met] => 541.36266666667
                [power] => 965.52728888889
            )

        [28] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:30
                [real_met] => 893.516
                [power] => 968.52582222222
            )

        [29] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:31
                [real_met] => 925.59333333333
                [power] => 964.59751111111
            )

        [30] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:32
                [real_met] => 1207.316
                [power] => 958.25177777778
            )

        [31] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:33
                [real_met] => 1087.3746666667
                [power] => 947.95448888889
            )

        [32] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:34
                [real_met] => 1242.88
                [power] => 941.74822222222
            )

        [33] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:35
                [real_met] => 1039.956
                [power] => 930.35844444444
            )

        [34] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:36
                [real_met] => 1048.324
                [power] => 924.84951111111
            )

        [35] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:37
                [real_met] => 1095.0453333333
                [power] => 923.36186666667
            )

        [36] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:38
                [real_met] => 1082.4933333333
                [power] => 919.20111111111
            )

        [37] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:39
                [real_met] => 1104.1106666667
                [power] => 911.94884444444
            )

        [38] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:40
                [real_met] => 1157.108
                [power] => 905.60311111111
            )

        [39] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:41
                [real_met] => 1268.6813333333
                [power] => 905.88204444444
            )

        [40] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:42
                [real_met] => 1092.9533333333
                [power] => 904.04573333333
            )

        [41] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:43
                [real_met] => 1172.4493333333
                [power] => 906.53288888889
            )

        [42] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:44
                [real_met] => 1486.9466666667
                [power] => 908.64813333333
            )

        [43] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:45
                [real_met] => 1456.264
                [power] => 900.90773333333
            )

        [44] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:46
                [real_met] => 1360.7293333333
                [power] => 884.38093333333
            )

        [45] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:47
                [real_met] => 1370.492
                [power] => 878.63955555556
            )

        [46] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:48
                [real_met] => 1394.2013333333
                [power] => 875.29235555556
            )

        [47] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:49
                [real_met] => 1398.3853333333
                [power] => 877.12866666667
            )

        [48] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:50
                [real_met] => 532.29733333333
                [power] => 878.89524444444
            )

        [49] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:51
                [real_met] => 631.31866666667
                [power] => 905.16146666667
            )

        [50] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:52
                [real_met] => 449.31466666667
                [power] => 930.68386666667
            )

        [51] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:53
                [real_met] => 569.256
                [power] => 960.73893333333
            )

        [52] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:54
                [real_met] => 291.02
                [power] => 988.33008888889
            )

        [53] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:55
                [real_met] => 420.02666666667
                [power] => 1013.3876
            )

        [54] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:56
                [real_met] => 386.55466666667
                [power] => 1035.7255111111
            )

        [55] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:57
                [real_met] => 465.35333333333
                [power] => 1066.8265777778
            )

        [56] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:58
                [real_met] => 794.49466666667
                [power] => 1091.2564888889
            )

        [57] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:00:59
                [real_met] => 631.31866666667
                [power] => 1106.4351111111
            )

        [58] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:01:00
                [real_met] => 775.66666666667
                [power] => 1132.7478222222
            )

        [59] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:01:01
                [real_met] => 735.22133333333
                [power] => 1138.0243111111
            )

        [60] => Array
            (
                [acumulate_time] => 00:01:02
                [real_met] => 898.39733333333
                [power] => 1143.6727111111
          )
     )
 )
```

I had developed following code of php to find out average of `real_met` index value of every 30 seconds

```
$end=1;
$start =0;
$sum=0;

                                        array_push($dataPoint['trkpt'],NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
$count_divide=0;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($dataPoint['trkpt'])-1;$i++)
{
  if( $end != 0 && ( $end % 30 == 0 || $i >= 7) )
  {
    for($j=$start;$j< $start + 30; $j++)
    {
      if($dataPoint['trkpt'][$j]!= NULL)
      {
            $count_divide++;
            $sum = $sum + $dataPoint['trkpt'][$j]['real_met'];              
      }
    }
    $dataPoint['trkpt'][$start]['power'] = $sum/$count_divide;
    $sum_power = $sum_power + $dataPoint['trkpt'][$start]['power'];
    $start++;
    $sum =0;
 }
$count_divide=0;
$end++;
}
```

How to resolved this issue ? Please Suggestion

[Google Excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdXhW6uNLBteW6DqIM7ZyDaFJyfxUJcof5LKs1b-MVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: So what is the result of your code?What doesnt work?

Comment: problem is that right now I'm just get value from 0 to 30 index, but actually average of `real_met` is depend on `acumulate` time duration let's see on 2 there is `acumulate_time` is `00:00:03` there is not fix gap now understand what said ?

Comment: average of `real_met` store in `power` index value, for example for index of 0 contain `power` index value is average of 0 to 30 index value

Comment: So when the sum of acumulate_time is 30 you want the average of real_met ?

Comment: I want be every 30 seconds calculate average store into index 0 then after  store into index 1 respectively

Comment: acumulate time is `[acumulate_time] => 00:00:01`

Comment: can you got idea what I said or not ?

Comment: ITs kinda hard ,I have to guess.Just edit your question with the desired array

Comment: yes, you are right dear, I don't get any logic about it because of some times `acumulate_time` index value of two index gap might be different like this if index of 0 acumulate time is `00:00:01` then index of 2 acumulate time is `00:00:05` at the moment how we got value from acumulate time from `00:00:00`  to `00:00:30` ?

Comment: please check google excel sheet data to understand well https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OdXhW6uNLBteW6DqIM7ZyDaFJyfxUJcof5LKs1b-MVQ/edit